# .NET 4.x WPF ComboBox Databinding SelectedIndex not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm updating my project from .NET Framework 3.5 to .NET Framework 4.5.1. Everything works, except my databinding to a ComboBox. The ComboBox is part of a Itemscontrol. The XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="AfmetingenLijst" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Lengte}" Tag="{Binding LID}" Margin="5,5,5,5"  TextChanged="UpdateList"/>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Breedte}" Tag="{Binding BID}" Margin="5,5,5,5" TextChanged="UpdateList"/>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Hoogte}" Tag="{Binding HID}" Margin="5,5,5,5" TextChanged="UpdateList"/>
                                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Naam}" Margin="5,5,5,5" />
                                <ComboBox Grid.Column="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=items}" SelectedIndex="{Binding geselecteerdProduct}" SelectedValuePath="Code" DisplayMemberPath = "Naam" SelectionChanged="UpdateList" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ComboBox>
                                <Button Tag="{Binding ID}" Grid.Column="5" Margin="5,5,5,5" Content="{Binding Title}" Click="Afmeting_handler" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

In C# a list is filled with the databinding values:

```
afm = new List<Afmeting>();
        if (afm.Count == 0)
        {
            afm.Add(new Afmeting() { ID = "+", LID = "L+", BID = "B+", HID = "H+", Title = "+", items = items });
            afm[afm.Count - 1].geselecteerdProduct = 0;
            afmetingen_counter++;


        }
        AfmetingenLijst.ItemsSource = afm;
```

The items in the ComboBox exists, I can select them by mouse. But by default SelectedIndex = -1. But in the list "geselecteerdProduct" (the databinding to SelectedIndex) is set to 0.

In .NET 3.5 it is working perfect, but in 4.x SelectedIndex and the value in "afm" is automatically set to -1.

Items is not empty, there are +- 5 items in the list.

Can someone help me?

Comment: isn't the selected index supposed to be in `geselecteerdProduct` ? where / how do you use it ? you're only setting it to 0 for some reason ...

Comment: Thats right. geselecteerdProduct is my selectedIndex. I set it to 0 to select the first item.

Comment: Are there any binding errors/warnings in your Outcome window? What is happening in your `UpdateList` method which if fired upon `SelectionChanged` event?

Comment: when you bind  the SelectedIndex to a property, the SelectionChanged event is fired. Is it possible that you do something in "UpdateList" that can cause this behaviour?

Comment: UpdateList is empty.

Comment: You can have a look at my article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/671544/Understanding-SelectedValue-SelectedValuePath-Sele), where you can dl a simple solution with working binding, and see where it differs ...

Comment: In your ComboBoxes SelectedIndex is also -1 at the start. I want to select the first. Besides that, I found out every time Items.Refresh() is called, the SelectedIndex is reset to -1. Maybe this is the problem when the list is initialised.I made a little project to demonstrate this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21846554/WpfApplication1Test.rar

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug for WPF.

When ComboBox is nested in ItemsControl, and set SelectedIndex and SelectedValuePath at the same time, ComboBox's OnSelectionChanged will be fired tiwce at initialize, but SelectionChanged only once.
[WPF ComboBox SelectedIndex debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krUkG.png):

To solve the problem is simple, just remove SelectedValuePath from the ComboBox.

XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="AfmetingenLijst" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Lengte}" Tag="{Binding LID}" Margin="5,5,5,5"  TextChanged="UpdateList"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Breedte}" Tag="{Binding BID}" Margin="5,5,5,5" TextChanged="UpdateList"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Hoogte}" Tag="{Binding HID}" Margin="5,5,5,5" TextChanged="UpdateList"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Naam}" Margin="5,5,5,5" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="4"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=items}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding geselecteerdProduct}"

                        DisplayMemberPath = "Naam"
                        SelectionChanged="UpdateList"
                        Height="25"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </ComboBox>
                <Button Tag="{Binding ID}" Grid.Column="5" Margin="5,5,5,5" Content="{Binding Title}" Click="Afmeting_handler" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```